# Give an array, find four unique ints that satisfy the following equation

Tags: python, algorithm

So I currently have a question that I'm attempting to solve:

- Given an array of L distinct integers that are all > 0, find if there are four integers that are unique that solve the following equation of ***a^2 + b - c^2 - d = 0***

I have to solve this problem with time complexity of O(n^2).

This is my current failing attempt at solving the problem:

I first rearrange the equation to make a^2 + b = c^2 + d, then I initialise a hash map.
I use a nested for loop to get pairs of elements. I save the sum of the first element squared + the second element. I then check if it is in the hash map.
If it is, I then return true as I found another distinct pair, else if not, I add it in the hashmap.

```
def solution(arr, n):
  
    Hash = {} # Introduce a hash map
      
    # Create a double for loop
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            eqt = arr[i]* arr[i] + arr[j] # Take the sum
 
            if eqt in Hash.keys():
                # Return true as another pair has been found
                print('Found')
                return True
            else:
                # Sum isnt in hash so store it
                Hash[eqt] = (arr[i], arr[j])
    return False
```

This solution seems to work for arrays that are ordered, but when they aren't, it fails
i.e: it works for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] => producing (1, 6) and (2, 3)
but doesn't work for [7,6,5,4,3,2,1].

Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If it works when it's ordered, have you thought about just ordering the array before passing it into your function?

Comment: If your solution works for sorted arrays, you can put `arr = sorted(arr)` as the first statement in your function.

Comment: Won't this effect the time complexity of needing to get O(n^2)

Comment: No, not necessarily. The slower sorting algorithms are at O(n^2), I don't know what algorithm python uses off of the top of my head, but I'm willing to bet it's much faster than that, probably around O(nlog(n)). If your code is at a complexity of O(n^2) already, the only way for it to make it worse than that would be if the sorting algorithm was worse than that, otherwise it should be fine.

Comment: So If I say, performed a merge-sort (time complexity of O(nlogn)), the overall time complexity of the function would remain n^2? Btw, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is at the range of the inner loop variable, `j`. It only looks *after* the `i`; but it should also look all the values (except `i`th) in the `arr`, not only after `i`.

So, fix is

```
def solution(arr, n):

    Hash = {} # Introduce a hash map

    # Create a double for loop
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):                   # main change is here!
            if i == j:                       # and here (excluding same element)
                continue

            eqt = arr[i]* arr[i] + arr[j] # Take the sum

            if eqt in Hash:
                # Return False as another pair has been found
                print("Found")
                return False
            else:
                # Sum isnt in hash so store it
                Hash[eqt] = (arr[i], arr[j])
    return True
```

Some other changes:

- It should return `False` I think when it finds a pair in the hash (according to the problem description, I understood this way)
- `for i in range(n)` instead of `n-1` to let it look at the last value too; complexity is the same overall
- `eqt in Hash` instead of over `keys`; same thing but more Pythonic

Testing:

```
>>> solution([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 7)
False
>>> solution([7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 7)
False
```

---

To assure distinctness of the pairs, we modify the `if` as (as @JoranBeasley mentions):

```
if eqt in Hash and not any(val in Hash[eqt] for val in (arr[i], arr[j])):
    ...
```

to check not any of the values in the candidate at hand i.e., `arr[i], arr[j]` is in the already-found pair i.e., `Hash[eqt]`.

Comment: I see, but I need the integers to be distinct. so for [1,2,3,4,5], (1,2) and (4, 1) can't be a solution as we have 2 1's

Comment: then just check if either are in the alternate solution as an extra check (I think youll have to do a little more... but thats the gist of it)

Comment: @DanielBozinovski Edited the answer for that case, need to change the `if` as @JoranBeasley mentions.